# Remove all one character words in string EXCEPT 'a' 'i' and 'o'

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, tr

I'm trying to parse a file with the single quotes removed, leaving behind some random 's's and whatnot.

So far I've tried:

```
echo "a b c d e f g h i o omgifack" | grep -o '[^bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUV]\{2,\\}' 
echo "a b c d e f g h i o omgifack" | tr -d '[bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyzBCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ]'
```

The example I based these off of:

```
echo "a b c d e f g h i o omgifack" | grep -o '[a-z]\{2,\\}'
```

Desired output:

```
>a i o omgifack
```

I can't seem to figure it out, but I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Open to solutions using awk, sed, tr, grep... anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: Please share desired output in a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use something like

```
echo "a b c d e f g h i o omgifack" | grep -wo '[[:alpha:]]\{2,\}\|[AIOaio]'
a
i
o
omgifack
```

This will isolate all whole words (because of `-w`) that are either more than two letters long (that's the `[[:alpha:]]\{2,\}` part) or one of `[AIOaio]`.

Note that if the text contains umlauts or accented characters (such as `ä`, `é`, `ß` etc.), `[[:alpha:]]` does include those iff grep is run under a locale that recognizes them as part of its alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b[^aio ]\b \?//Ig' file
```

Remove any singleton characters which are not `a`,`i` or `u` (upper or lower case) followed by a possible space.